# postgrest deployment on ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postgrest

Hi I have an aws EC2 instance with ubuntu 14.04 installed.

I also have a remote postgres database to which I already have made a ssh tunnel in the port 5433 of my instance and is working.

So I want to make the api for the database with [postgrest](http://postgrest.com/)

The current server already has apache and postgrest installed.
And when I run the postgrest process everything looks fine but I have not been able to access the api.

I try to make requests like XX.XXX.XX.XXX:8000/users and it doesn´t works.
Just says that the server took too long to respond.

I think it might be a thing of the port (I am already using the 3000 for other thing), maybe the route I am using to access the api or the permission to access from another part.

Any advice would be great. Thanks

Comment: Did you open port 8000 in the security group?

Comment: SPECIFY THE LOCATION YOU TRY TO ACCESS YOUR RESTAPI!!!!!
Are you trying to access it inside EC2 ? Or you try to access it from Internet?  stackoverlow are not telepathic.

Comment: A simple "netstat -an | less " in both source and destination will show enough information for diagnosis.

Comment: I am trying to access from internet, sorry I have little expertise with web servers. I already have in the EC2 security group a rule allowing inbound and outbound requests from any IP.